# Trying to get max fps from Android Camera

Tags: android, camera, buffer, frame-rate

I'm developing an Android application, and I need to get the max of fps from the Camera.

I've been trying to implement the setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer but I can't get it to work.

Can anyone give me an example or an explanation?

I've set a timer, that runs every 10 milliseconds and there I run takePicture().Is that correct, or what is the way to get max fps ?

I already searched everywhere but I can't find an explanation that works for me.

Thank You.

Edit 2:

```
startRecording.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(!recording)
    {
        recording = true;
        thread.start();

        cam.startPreview();     
        Size previewSize=cam.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
        int dataBufferSize=(int)(previewSize.height*previewSize.width*(ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(cam.getParameters().getPreviewFormat())/8.0));

        cam.addCallbackBuffer(new byte[dataBufferSize]);
        cam.addCallbackBuffer(new byte[dataBufferSize]);
        cam.addCallbackBuffer(new byte[dataBufferSize]);
        cam.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(new PreviewCallback() {
            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] imageData, Camera arg1) {
                try {
                    photos.add(imageData);
                } catch(Exception e) {                                                                  System.out.println("ERROR!");
                }

            }
        });
    }
(...)
```

Thank You!

Comment: Please explain, completely and precisely, what "I can't get it to work" means. "Is that correct" -- no.

Comment: @CommonsWare I just added code to the topic and some notes. Can you understand now?
Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem #1: Timer

Quoting [the documentation for `setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer%28android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback%29):

> Installs a callback to be invoked for every preview frame, using buffers supplied with addCallbackBuffer(byte[]), in addition to displaying them on the screen. The callback will be repeatedly called for as long as preview is active and buffers are available. Any other preview callbacks are overridden.

So, delete your `Timer`. Call `setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer()` once, and you will be called with preview frames, as they are ready for processing.

## Problem #2: Hardcoded Buffer Size

Quoting [the documentation for `addCallbackBuffer()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#addCallbackBuffer%28byte%5B%5D%29):

> For formats besides YV12, the size of the buffer is determined by multiplying the preview image width, height, and bytes per pixel. The width and height can be read from getPreviewSize(). Bytes per pixel can be computed from getBitsPerPixel(int) / 8, using the image format from getPreviewFormat().
>
> If using the YV12 format, the size can be calculated using the equations listed in setPreviewFormat(int).

Please follow those instructions, rather than guessing at a buffer size.

## Problem #3: Adding the Buffers

Further quoting [the documentation for `addCallbackBuffer()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#addCallbackBuffer%28byte%5B%5D%29):

> Adds a pre-allocated buffer to the preview callback buffer queue. Applications can add one or more buffers to the queue. When a preview frame arrives and there is still at least one available buffer, the buffer will be used and removed from the queue. Then preview callback is invoked with the buffer. If a frame arrives and there is no buffer left, the frame is discarded. Applications should add buffers back when they finish processing the data in them.

Call `addCallbackBuffer()` for a few buffers up front, when you call `setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer()`. In `onPreviewFrame()`, arrange for a background thread to process that frame's buffer. When that work is done, add that same buffer back to the pool by calling `addCallbackBuffer()`. Do **NOT** just keep allocating new buffers.

Comment: I edited the topic and change the code to what I have now, following what you said.
My question is how can I get more captures? Actually I only get 3 captures.
Other question is why my saved photo appear all black?

You said "When that work is done, add that same buffer back to the pool by calling addCallbackBuffer()". How can I do that? I can't understand.
Many Thanks!!

Comment: @user2989493: You appear to have missed most of the suggestions for problem #3. `photos.add()` does not seem like that it is doing work on a background thread. And I fail to see where you are adding a processed buffer back to the pool via `addCallbackBuffer()` when that background thread work is complete.

Comment: I'm adding the byte[] to an ArrayList, and after that the "thread" do the work(save the byte[] to bitmap). Is that a wrong approach? Regarding to addCallbackBuffer() I can't understand how I do that. Can you explain please? Thank You!!

Comment: @user2989493: "Is that a wrong approach?" -- since I don't see the code, I cannot answer that. However, it does not sound good, as multiple threads cannot work off the same `ArrayList` (use something else, like a `LinkedBlockingQueue`). "Regarding to addCallbackBuffer() I can't understand how I do that" -- you claim to have a thread. That thread is running some code to process a `byte[]`. When that code is done, the last thing you do is call `addCallbackBuffer()` to add that `byte[]` back to the pool of buffers.

Comment: Now I can get around 25 fps. The problem is the saved photos are black images. Do you have a hint, or you need that i post the code? Many thanks !! ;)

Comment: @user2989493: I would recommend that you open a fresh Stack Overflow question, where you show your code (including how you are saving the photos and converting from YUV into something more ordinary), link to a sample saved image, and so on. With regards to the fps rate, you would want to add some logging or something to determine if you are being limited due to running out of buffers, or if that is just all the faster the preview frames are becoming available.

Comment: @user2989493: You also should show where and how you are attaching your preview `Surface`, as I do not see where you are doing that.